# "Bootstrap" python script in the Windows shell without .py / .pyw associations

Tags: python, shell

Sometimes (in customer's PCs) I need a python script to execute in the Windows shell like a .CMD or .BAT, but without having the .py or .pyw extensions associated with PYTHON / PYTHONW.

I came out with a pair of 'quick'n dirty' solutions:

1)

```
"""
e:\devtool\python\python.exe %0 :: or %PYTHONPATH%\python.exe
goto eof:
""" 
# Python test
print "[works, but shows shell errors]"
```

2)

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=4 delims=xxx" %%l in (%0) do @echo %%l | e:\devtools\python\python.exe
goto :eof
::----------

# Python test
print "[works better, but is somewhat messy]"
```

Do you know a better solution? (ie: more concise or elegant)

---

Update:

based on @van answer, the more concise way I found (without setting ERRORLEVEL)

```
@e:\devtools\python\python.exe -x "%~f0" %* & exit /b

### Python begins....
import sys

for arg in sys.argv:
    print arg

raw_input("It works!!!\n")

###
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your second solution (other than that `||` should be `|`).  It's not super-elegant, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try to create a script what is both `python` and `windows shell script`. In this case you can name you file `my_flexible_script.bat` and execute it either directly or via `python ...`.

See a content of `pylint.bat` file from [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/cgi-bin/hgwebdir.cgi/pylint/file/f5f084e5267a/bin/pylint.bat):

```
@echo off
rem = """-*-Python-*- script
rem -------------------- DOS section --------------------
rem You could set PYTHONPATH or TK environment variables here
python -x "%~f0" %*
goto exit

"""
# -------------------- Python section --------------------
import sys
from pylint import lint
lint.Run(sys.argv[1:])


DosExitLabel = """
:exit
exit(ERRORLEVEL)
rem """
```

It is similar to what you do, but has more compliant `dual-script` support.

Comment: Good one, the rem=""" trick! That's what I was looking for, thx

Comment: This type of program is known as a polyglot (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_%28computing%29).

Comment: Why doesn't the `@echo off` trigger a Syntax Error exception?

Comment: @TimPietzcker From `python --help`; `-x: skip first line of source, allowing use of non-Unix forms of #!cmd`

Comment: "from __future__ import" should be the first thing in the python script before any other import.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following [distutils](http://docs.python.org/distutils/)/[py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) script to produce a single runnable executable file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
    console = [{'script': "MyScript.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

I see that `MSVCR71.DLL` gets copied into the dist directory as a result... but the chances are high that this dependancy is already on the target machine.

Comment: I should mention that I don't want to freeze the script, because my main purpose is using it like a "shell program on steroids", keeping it easily editable and modifiable